# Using "dotnet publish", it gives error as "Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore". Is there Nuget package issue.?

Tags: asp.net, .net, jenkins

I created jenkins pipeline for .net app using msbuild. Build is successful but when I publish using "dotnet publish", it gives error as "Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore" What will be missing. Thing so I an facing issue? Is it Nuget?